# Access Modules in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, module

I have build a module in Flex that I call myModule, this module has a method myMethod. Now I use the ModuleManager to load this module.

```
mod = ModuleManager.getModule("myModule.swf");
mod.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, modEventHandler);
mod.load();
```

now I want to access the method

```
(customComp as myModule).myMethod()
```

where customComp is the DisplayObject created by the factore.create() method of the module info. This code will not compile as myModule is not a defined property. Can someone help me with that? What do I have to import? The myModule.swf is not an asset, it lies in the bin directory of my project.

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how the module manager works.  But generally I use a  module loader to display my modules.  However there were only 2 ways I have seen to access a modules functions.

You can access the function directly by:

```
mod.child.myMethod();
```

Or you need to create an interface for that module.

```
var ichild:* = mod.child as IMyModule;
ichild.myMethod();
```

More info can be found [here](http://www.flexcodemonkey.com/blog/?p=55)

I believe accessing the module directly like in the first example should work however I always use an interface.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you are right, interfaces work or you have to put the class in the working directory =) my fault